# dynamically add javascript array to img src

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript array, (not jquery) which I can pull the code needed for src:

```
var imp = code1 [5];
document.getElementById("prodimg").src=imp;
```

with HTML of

```
<img  id="prodimg">
```

I am trying to set up a system where pressing code2 will bring up the picture for code 2 etc.  So the var imp, will change to code2 [5] when code 2 is clicked.

I have it working for some other data on click, but I am having issues writing to get the specific array back into the img tag.

I was thinking along the lines of

```
  function changeimg(code)
```

or

```
 function changeimg (code, array)

function changeimg (code, [5])
{
  imp = code [5]
}
```

But its not working and Im sure there is an easier way

Js fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/9aUq8  with some broken function efforts  where each button would change the src of the image to its own array

Or http://jsfiddle.net/9aUq8/1/ shows number 1, and the array for B[2] is the number 2.  What function would bring up b[2] showing the number 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Is the position you want always `5` through multiple arrays? I see you have `code1[5]` and `code2[5]` -- these are 2 different arrays at position 5.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate? It's really hard to follow what you are saying.

Comment: yes always the same array position, from multiple arrays.  Something along the lines of http://jsfiddle.net/9aUq8/  where each button changes the img

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9aUq8/1/  has my functions that dont work taken out, and maybe a clearer idea.  Click B and the pic showing 2 appears

Comment: That Fiddle results *only* in a lot of `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined` messages in the console.

Comment: yes Im looking to define the function xcode so it works.  Now its not defined and wont do anything because the goal is to click it and change the src, but Im not sure how.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use the `window['name_array'][index]` like in the function from this example.

```
<script>
var code1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var code2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
function setCodeSrc(code, ix) {
  document.getElementById("prodimg").src = window[code][ix];
}

setCodeSrc('code1', 3);
</script>
```

Or better, the arrays into an object.

```
<script>
var codes = {
  'code1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  'code2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
};

function setCodeSrc(code, ix) {
  document.getElementById("prodimg").src = codes[code][ix];
}

setCodeSrc('code2', 2);
</script>
```

Comment: thanks - Im slow at JS but it looks interesting.  But yes I think the 1st example is what I was looking for.  The ix is generic?

Comment: The ix is not generic, it is just a property /variable name.

Comment: yes sorry, what I meant to say that the ix is not an absolute javascript variable, but a relative one created for the function, and can be called anything?

Answer (score 0):

CoursesWeb is prob a lot better but I did it like this:

```
    function displayArrayAsImage( array ) {

  var picurl = array[2];

  var html = 'img/';    

    html +=  picurl ;

  html += '.jpg';

  return html;
}

 var getimg = document.getElementById("prodimg");
```

//inset image at load

```
   getimg.src = displayArrayAsImage (code1);
```

//change image on click

```
function change(code)
{

    getimg.src = displayArrayAsImage (code); 

}
```